# Universal Link From safari not taking

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-links

I am trying to open the app from the safari , so I have done the universal link setup . When I try to open the app from mail link it was working . When I try it from the safari it is opening the website and then the banner appears to open the app .

[image]

But I want the app open directly instead of safari redirection .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="https://www.path.com/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Moet"  >Instant Impact</a></p>
</body>
</html>

{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
      "details": [
           {
             "appID": "ZZZZZZ.com.xxx.yyy",
             "paths": ["/*"]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clear what is this file you attached? What do expect from it?

Comment: I have added the html file where I am redirecting user to one website , below you can see apple-app-site-association file there I have not given any path , so it has to open the application if is is installed . but it is directly going to website instead of opening the application . @LiazKamper